# how composite text over image

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a movie (rusty_chain). In this movie i want to add descriptive text on top. How can i do this with compositing?

I know i can do it with video sequencer, just a layer on top of it, but if i try it in compositor (because i want to animate the text), i do not find a node which just basically adds the text on the movie.

sorry, for the stupid question...it's my first try compositing...

[image: node setup]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to make sure that the background of your render is transparent, render, then plug the text alpha into the alpha socket of the *Alpha Over*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i do not know whether it has a transparent background...sorry i am new to Blender...but i love it ;) i also tried to upload the blend file and copied the link...but i do not see the blend file in my question :(

Comment: you need to pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and save, then use this site (read the instructions and when you've upload, copy paste the link it gives you): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: got it, worked, thank you!!! i mean the uploading of the blend file....not the "real" problem ;)

Comment: ok I've edited my answer, please check and tell me if it works

Comment: works perfect! thank you! did not know that there was this "transparent" flag...

Comment: I don't know why the Compositor preview is cut off though, but the render works fine